# ionic platform add android: Error: Cannot find module ‘./source-map/source-map-generator’

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, bower, source-maps, node-modules

I am facing with strange problem. I just create a blank app. When I tried to add android paltform I faced with this error: Error: Cannot find module './source-map/source-map-generator'
Also, when I try to build my app I get the same error. I am really confused with this error.

Is there any solution?

best regards,
hosein

Comment: What is your os? Linux?

Comment: No, I am using windows 10. @tinybyte

Answer (score 0):

either **npm install source-map** 
try this command with terminal and then build or create a  project other than blank.

Comment: I tried this before but it does not work. @shivanshu-verma

Comment: then you should try to create a  tab project by command ionic start <your_app_name> tabs because some time blank  project creation give such error.

Comment: However, this is not a solution. I want to build an apk on my exiting project.